# Logical error in my prime number program

Tags: c#, primes

Can someone identify the logical error in my program. I am only getting result of 2 and 3 as prime numbers.

Algorithm is given below:

int outer;

int inner;

int count=0;

for (outer = 2; outer <= 100; outer++)

{

for (inner = 2; inner <= outer; inner++)

{

if (outer % inner == 0)

count = count + 1;

}

if (count == 1)

{

Console.WriteLine("prime is {0}", inner - 1);

count = 0;

}

else if (count > 1)

Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a prime", inner - 1);

}

Comment: **[Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Declaring variables at the top like in ancient C is not necessary in C#, and leads here to the suspicious pattern of resetting `count` only in some cases but not others.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you. The problem was with the count. I repost the corrected code

for (outer = 2; outer <= 100; outer++)

```
        {

            for (inner = 2; inner <= outer; inner++)

                if (outer % inner == 0)
                    count = count + 1;

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("prime is {0}", inner - 1);
                    count = 0;
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                    count = 0;
```